# Minimum value of trigonometric function in the form asinx- bcosx

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a way to find the minimum value of the equation $$y = (4\sin x - 6\cos x)^2 - 3$$  without using calculus or graphing the function?

I wrote $4\sin x - 6\cos x$ in the form $R\sin(x-a)$ where  $a$ is a constant. I got $2\sqrt{13}\sin(x-56.31^\circ)$. However, I am unable to find the least value of the given equation but I could find the greatest value as $(2\sqrt{13})^2 - 3$ as the greatest value of sine function is $1$ so a factor of $2\sqrt{13}$ multiplied and then squared would give me 52 then a vertical translation by vector $(0,-3)$ would give the max value as 49. Using a similar approach by knowing the least value of sine function is $-1$, I could not work out the minimum of the original equation.

Comment: The least value happens when $(\cdot)^2=0$, i.e. when $\sin(x-a)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the square of any real number is nonnegative,
$$(4\sin x-6\cos x)^2\geq0$$
Add $-3$ to both sides
$$f(x)\geq -3$$
So, the minimum value of $f$ is $\boxed{-3}$.

---

Since your title says a different thing, let me write that out too. As you said, we can write
$$a\sin x\pm b\cos x =d\sin (x\pm c)$$
where $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, from the derivation (I presume you know this as you used it).

Since the sine lies between $-1$ and $1$,
$$-1\leq \sin (x-c)\leq 1$$
Multiplying by $d$ (square root is always positive and so is $d$),
$$-d\leq d\sin(x-c)\leq d$$
or
$$\boxed{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\leq a\sin x\pm b\cos x\leq\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

---

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: In the first way, aren’t you supposed to subtract $3$? The minimum is actually $-3$.

Comment: Yes the minimum is -3

Comment: @talbi: Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

A square is nonnegative, the smallest value $y$ is $-3$ which is attained when $\tan x = \frac32$.

Answer (score 1):

$(6/4)$ is in the range of $\tan(x)$.

This implies that there is a value of $(x)$ such that

$\frac{4\sin(x) - 6\cos(x)} {\cos(x)} = 0$, which minimizes the function.